# How can I play local co-op with only a single keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, sacred-citadel

I would like to play [Sacred Citadel](http://store.steampowered.com/app/207930/) in local co-op together with my sister. How would I be able to emulate a controller on the PC and have us both use the keyboard instead, as the game "requires" you to use a controller?

Comment: This would depend greatly on what game you're playing.  Some don't allow local hotseat multiplayer, and no amount of emulation can change that.